# How can i get the char by having the value of that char in the ascii table?

Tags: c++, ascii

I've been trying for a long time, searching a lot online, but I can't find anything about it...
I have an integer given by a function. This integer is the value of a char in the ascii table and I want to know what char it is. I've tried functions like toascii() or _itoa(), but none of these seems the right one...
Can you tell me what function should I use and with what parameteres?
Thanks.

Comment: `static_cast<char>(integer)`?

Comment: Show the code. I guess it is that char. `int x = 31; std::cout << (char)x;`

Comment: Welcome to [so] ... While I haven't downvoted you, I'll explain why you got downvoted.  Please read [mcve] for more details.

Comment: What do you mean? A character in the ASCII table and its integer value is the same thing. The character 'A' *IS* the integer '65' and vice versa..

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy, no function needed, just assign it. In C++ chars **are** integers.

```
int char_value = ...;
char actual_char = char_value;
cout << actual_char << '\n';
```

You might add a cast to that assignment but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Worth noting that this assumes (usually a safe assumption these days) that the system uses ASCII encoding for output..

Answer (score 2):

> This integer is the value of a char in the ascii table and I want to know what char it is

you do not need any function

```
char theChar = (char) theNumber;
```

or better

```
char theChar = static_cast<char>(theNumber);
```

Comment: perhaps use the c++ approach of `static_cast<char> (theNumber)`

Comment: Agreed. But you can make everyone happy with *or `char theChar = static_cast<char> (theNumber);`

Comment: @user4581301 ok, if that make you happy, I did ;-)

Comment: @AhmedMasud you was two asking for that, so I edited to do ;-)

Comment: To be honest I wasn't asking anything. I just couldn't pass up a chance to drop a Dune quote.

Comment: LOL you didn't have to make me happy, perhaps I was overzealous with my comment.

Comment: @AhmedMasud there is no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I fixed it on my own, I don't know why but my IDE didn't let me do something like char CharVar = IntVar. Now somehow I fixed it and it works properly.